# Crystal Reports - Returning next value in column

Tags: crystal-reports

Need some help on crystal reports:
We are currently using crystal reports at work to generate confirmation papers to internal counterparties.
These confirmations are automatically triggered by our system when we set the interest rate on a specific deal.
The parameters that are sent from our external system are "deal number" and "action number". This information is passed on from the "events" database table, containing following columns:

[image: some columns from Events table]

The confirmation generated by performing the rate set contains specific information regarding interest payments we expect from counterparties.
So this confirmation generated has unique parameters, being the rateset "action number" and "deal number" from events table (see attached).

Now in this confirmation, we also want to make a reference to the "Next RateSet" date.

We tried to solve this by inserting an SQL statement to:

> select top (1) effective date from events table where the
>   comments=rate set and where the action no = 0

This logic however does not hold up when we have to generate backdated confirmations.

So in theory, I would like to perform a select statement where I select the first record where the "event no" is larger than the "event no" from the current generated confirmation.

I'm not sure how to perform this though, as I've read it's not possible to use a crystal parameter in the SQL selection.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the table a 2nd time to the report.
Crystal would assign an Alias to the 2nd instance by adding a number to the table name. 
To make things more intuitive, change that alias to something like 'NextRateSet'.

Join the Events table to its alias on:

```
Events.Dealno = NextRateSet.Dealno AND
Events.EffectiveDate < NextRateSet.EffectiveDate
```

Add record selection criteria of:

```
NextRateSet.ActionNo = 0
```

Group the report on Events.DealNo and Sort it Descending by NextRateSet.EffectiveDate. 
Suppress the detail section and move everything to the Group Footer.
Since the Group footer shows the last record in the group, it would show the earliest NextRateSet.EffectiveDate. And since that alias is restricted to EffectiveDates following the Events.EffectiveDate, you get the correct date.

Comment: Thank you, I will test your proposal tomorrow by joining a second table, sounds like a creative solution.

I will inform you when successful :)